# Create Tabs which affect only particular area of the GUI

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt4

I would like to create tabs which target only a specific area within the GUI.
That is there should be an area of the GUI which is static and always present even when changing tab.
I have already created tabs as according to the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabs    = QtGui.QTabWidget()

    # Create tabs
    tab1    = QtGui.QWidget()   
    tab2    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab3    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab4    = QtGui.QWidget()

    # Resize width and height
    tabs.resize(1000, 1000)

    # Set layout of first tab
    vBoxlayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    pushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
    pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Settings")
    pushButton3 = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton1)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton2)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton3)
    tab1.setLayout(vBoxlayout)   

    # Add tabs
    tabs.addTab(tab1,"Tab 1")
    tabs.addTab(tab2,"Tab 2")
    tabs.addTab(tab3,"Tab 3")
    tabs.addTab(tab4,"Tab 4")

    # Set title and show
    tabs.setWindowTitle('PyQt QTabWidget @ pythonspot.com')
    tabs.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And so, what is the expected result exactly ?

Comment: There should just be an area in the GUI frame which is static upon tab switching, where widgets can be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is several solution to achieve this.
I will give an example.

First of all, you need to create a main window, where you will create a layout with 2 frames (I took gridlayout for this example). Once done, you can now set one layout per frame, and add widget as you want in those layout. It will populate the frame. So you can populate one frame with your tabs, and one which stay fix.

I did not take in consideration size of the widget, you can fit them as you want.

I just modified a little your example :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()

    mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(mainWindow)

    frameLeft = QtGui.QFrame(mainWindow)
    frameLeft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    frameLeft.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
    gridLayoutLeft = QtGui.QGridLayout(frameLeft)
    mainLayout.addWidget(frameLeft, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    frameRigth = QtGui.QFrame(mainWindow)
    frameRigth.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    frameRigth.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
    gridLayoutRigth = QtGui.QGridLayout(frameRigth)
    mainLayout.addWidget(frameRigth, 0, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    tabs    = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    gridLayoutRigth.addWidget(tabs, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    button = QtGui.QPushButton('test')
    gridLayoutLeft.addWidget(button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    # Create tabs
    tab1    = QtGui.QWidget()   
    tab2    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab3    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab4    = QtGui.QWidget()

    # Set layout of first tab
    vBoxlayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    pushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
    pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Settings")
    pushButton3 = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton1)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton2)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton3)
    tab1.setLayout(vBoxlayout)   

    # Add tabs
    tabs.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
    tabs.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2")
    tabs.addTab(tab3, "Tab 3")
    tabs.addTab(tab4, "Tab 4")

    # Set title and show
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('PyQt QTabWidget @ pythonspot.com')
    mainWindow.resize(mainWindow.sizeHint())
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope this help !